# BIZTALK , Went to bulid a Web services that have connection to the Data of my orchestraction Biztalk

Tags: biztalk

My question is how can i get the information (Node of my schema) of my orchestraction biztalk in the web Services that i went to build.

Thank you very mutch  in advence

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you have an orchestration, and you wish to expose it as a web service, you should use the 'BizTalk Web Services publishing wizard' or the 'Biztalk WCF publishing wizard', depending on the version of BizTalk you're using

Comment: In the end i need to do consuming of my orchestraction, so i need to build a Web services that is going to have information of my orchestraction and that i have no idea how to do that